# Calculating p-value with Python. One-tailed or two-tailed?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, scipy.stats

I'm using this function to calculate the p-value of an experiment I'm running. I'm not sure if it's one-tailed or two-tailed. How can I infer this from the code? Thanks

```
from scipy import stats

def get_pvalue(con_conv, test_conv, con_size, test_size):  
    lift =  - abs(test_conv - con_conv)

    scale_one = con_conv * (1 - con_conv) * (1 / con_size)
    scale_two = test_conv * (1 - test_conv) * (1 / test_size)
    scale_val = (scale_one + scale_two)**0.5

    p_value = 2 * stats.norm.cdf(lift, loc = 0, scale = scale_val )

    return p_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two-tailed.** This can be inferred because the difference uses an absolute value, and the `p_value` multiplies the (one-sided) tail of the normal CDF by 2.